# Assuming user in Wordpress API

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a custom plugin for Wordpress that is a couple of RESTful APIs so I can do things from external systems.

I have the plugin working and can access the API, but when I attempt to run certain commands inside the plugin, I'm blocked because I don't have access. Inside the API code, I'm not logging anyone in, I'm just "the system", and I'm unclear in WP how to basically say "Assume or give me the permissions of this user so I can do the function".

If I output the command $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); I'm gettng

```
{"data":{},"ID":0,"caps":[],"cap_key":null,"roles":[],"allcaps":[],"filter":null}
```

Am I supposed to be logging in as a user inside of my API routine?

Answer (score 0):

solved, found wp_set_current_user();